# batch delete old files and empty folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2008

I have a batch file that works on my local machine (Windows 7), but doesn't fully work on the server it is intended to live on(Windows 2008 R2 Service Pack 1).

It needs to delete files older than a specified number of days in all listed folders, then delete empty folders and sub-folders.

Script:

```
set DaysOld=3
set "folders[0]=C:\Test\BatchDel\1"
set "folders[1]=C:\Test\BatchDel\2"
set "folders[2]=C:\Test\BatchDel\3"
set "folders[3]=C:\Test\BatchDel\DNE"


for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%s in ('set folders[') do (
    forfiles /p "%%t" /s /m * /D -%DaysOld% /C "cmd /c del @path"
)

for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /ad/b/s ^| sort /R') do rd "%%d"
pause
```

When run on my local machine (spacing added):

```
C:\Test\BatchDel>set DaysOld=3
C:\Test\BatchDel>set "folders[0]=C:\Test\BatchDel\1"
C:\Test\BatchDel>set "folders[1]=C:\Test\BatchDel\2"
C:\Test\BatchDel>set "folders[2]=C:\Test\BatchDel\3"
C:\Test\BatchDel>set "folders[3]=C:\Test\BatchDel\DNE"

C:\Test\BatchDel>for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %s in ('set folders[') do (forfiles /p "%t" /s /m * /D -3 /C "cmd /c del @path" )
C:\Test\BatchDel>(forfiles /p "C:\Test\BatchDel\1" /s /m * /D -3 /C "cmd /c del@path" )
ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria.
C:\Test\BatchDel>(forfiles /p "C:\Test\BatchDel\2" /s /m * /D -3 /C "cmd /c del@path" )
ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria.
C:\Test\BatchDel>(forfiles /p "C:\Test\BatchDel\3" /s /m * /D -3 /C "cmd /c del@path" )
ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria.
C:\Test\BatchDel>(forfiles /p "C:\Test\BatchDel\DNE" /s /m * /D -3 /C "cmd /c del @path" )
ERROR: The specified directory does not exist.

C:\Test\BatchDel>for /F "delims=" %d in ('dir /ad/b/s | sort /R') do rd "%d"

C:\Test\BatchDel>rd "C:\Test\BatchDel\3"
C:\Test\BatchDel>rd "C:\Test\BatchDel\2"
C:\Test\BatchDel>rd "C:\Test\BatchDel\1"
The directory is not empty.

C:\Test\BatchDel>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

When I run it on the server it asks for permission to delete each folder. (spacing added).

```
F:\data\Scripts>set DaysOld=5
F:\data\Scripts>set "folders[0]=F:\data\Environments\TestA\Cache_Data"
F:\data\Scripts>set "folders[1]=F:\data\Environments\TestB\Cache_Data"

F:\data\Scripts>for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %s in ('set folders[') do (forfiles /p "%t" /s /m * /D -5 /C "cmd /c del @path" )
F:\data\Scripts>(forfiles /p "F:\data\Environments\TestA\Cache_Data" /s /m * /D -5 /C "cmd /c del @path" )

F:\data\Environments\TestA\Cache_Data\0432f59d-9fd1-46ed-8579-9ebe358113fb\*, Are you sure (Y/N)?
```

I need it to delete the empty folders on the server without pressing Y for each one.

EDIT: 
I updated the script. Thanks aschipfl! it is now closer to working.  It is now asking Y/N to delete each folder.

EDIT 2: updated the outputs.

Comment: 1. I'd use syntax `set "folders[0]=C:\Test\BatchDel\1"`, so the doublequotes are not part of the variable value; this avoids double-doublequotes (see `forfiles` outputs); 2. I'd change the file mask of `forfiles` to `/m *` as `*.*` does not match all files (such with no extension are skipped by `forfiles` strangely); 3. I'd change the second loop to `for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /ad/b/s ^| sort /R') do`;

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks! this helped, I updated the script in the question to match the one I'm currently using.  It is now asking for Y/N for each file even though there is a /Q in there.

Comment: I think, the `/Q` switch of `rd` has no effect, unless you state `/S` too (but this is not what you want)... the sample output data does now no longer belong to the (modified) script, please correct that...

Comment: @aschipfl I took out the /Q and updated the sample outputs.

Comment: If you confirm the `Y/N` query with `Y`, what happens, is the respective (sub-)directory removed? perhaps some directories are write-protected (read-only attribute set) or you lack of access permissions? (by the way, the `set` syntax in the script and in the sample outputs are not the same...)

Comment: If I press `Y` it doesn't actually delete the folder.  If I just type this command in command prompt it deletes the folders 

`rd "F:\data\Environments\TestA\Cache_Data\0432f59d-9fd1-46ed-8579-9ebe358113fb\previews" "F:\data\Environments\TestA\Cache_Data\0432f59d-9fd1-46ed-8579-9ebe358113fb\"`

Comment: You can simulate you pressing `y` to each request with `echo y | rd "C:\Users\Wherever\"`

Comment: In the very last line of your sample server output data, there is `\*` appended to the directory path; the question is: where does this come from? the `*` constitutes a wildcard; perhaps this causes `rd` to ask for confirmation; on the other hand, as far as I know, `rd` does not accept wildcards (`*`, `?`) at all, and the `(Y/N)` query appears only in case `/S` is provided; so all this leads to the following question: are you really sure the script on the server is equal to that on your local machine?

Comment: Just re-copied the script over, it is the same except for the folder paths.  I messed around a bit more and if I `/m *.*` instead of `/m *` it doesn't ask `Y|N`. (but the folders are all still there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%s in ('set folders[') do (
    forfiles /p "%%t" /s /m *.* /D -%DaysOld% /C "cmd /c del @path"
    for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir "%%t" /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d"
)
```